# Не открывается ссылка при использовании скрипта JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использовал скрипт jquery для счетчика нажатий на ссылку.

```
<script defer>
$( document ).ready(function() {
 var link = $("#link"),
     counter = $("#counter");
 link.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var ajax = $.ajax({
   method : 'post',
   url : 'counter.php',
   dataType : 'text',
   data : { 'count' : 1 }
  });
  ajax.done(function(data){
   data = JSON.parse(data);
   counter.html(parseInt(data));
  }) ;
 });
});
```

Но перестало открывать саму ссылку в браузере. Просто обновляется счетчик нажатий, а переход не срабатывает. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать что бы скрипт работал и по ссылке переходил пользователь. Только открываю для себя удивительный мир JavaScript и поэтому использовал чужой скрипт.

код html

```
Установок: <span id="counter"><?=$cnt?></span> <a href="<?=$link?>" class="btn btn-primary mt-1" id="link">Установить</a>
```

Пробовал обернуть ссылку в span c id='link', пробовал внутри ссылки такой span. Не помогает.
Можно подумать что нет логики в этом, зачем обновлять счетчик если уходит по ссылке, но ссылка имеет вид href='tg://' и пользователь переходит по ней и остается на странице, но открывается приложение Telegram. Но можно обойтись без обновления счетчика, мне главное что бы POST отправился и пользователя отправила по ссылке. Т.е. посчитался клик.  Подскажите как сделать.

Дело полагаю дело в e.preventDefault, а без него не работает. т.е. сразу переходит по ссылке без отправки запроса

Comment: `preventDefault` отключает переход.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ajax.done(function(data) {
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  counter.html(parseInt(data));
  link[0].click();
});
```

```js
function clickLink() {
  $('#link')[0].click();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link" href="https://www.google.ca">Google</a>
<button onclick="clickLink()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Ничего не происходит когда так пробую.

Comment: @web555 Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.

Comment: спасибо большое.

Comment: @web555 Пожалуйста. Успехов.

Answer (score 0):

```
ajax.done(function(data){
   data = JSON.parse(data);
   counter.html(parseInt(data));
   window.location = link.attr('href');
  }) ;
```

Разобрался.

Comment: https://sprosi.pro/questions/1786779/jquery-kak-vyizvat-polzovatelskuyu-funktsiyu-pered-perehodom-po-ssyilke

Comment: Подозреваю переводы stackoverflow с других языков. Похожая проблема у человека. Я долго гуглил и нашел ответ. Если вам интересно то сначала я пробовал такое решение: https://qna.habr.com/q/399059 Но ничего не получалось.